# jquery plugin pictures fade in/out

Tags: jquery, plugins, slider, fadein, carousel

Does anyone know of a small footprint jquery plugin which acts like a slider but fades in the image(s) instead.

I found this http://nivo.dev7studios.com/ but it seems pretty heavy. Does anyone know of a simple plugin?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Here's a lightweight way of doing things that I've used.

HTML:

```
<div id="feature">
    <div id="overlay"></div>
    <div class="slide" style="background: url(image.jpg) no-repeat;">
    <h2>Driven by strategy</h2>
    </div>
    <div class="slide" style="background: url(image.jpg) no-repeat;">
    <h2>Committed to our relationships</h2>
    </div>
    <div class="slide" style="background: url(image.jpg) no-repeat;">
    <h2>Changing it up </h2>
    </div>
</div>
```

CSS:

```
/* Feature */
#feature {
    width: 990px;
    height: 500px;
    overflow: hidden;
    position: relative;
}

#feature .slide {
    width: 990px;
    height: 500px;
}

#feature #overlay {
    position: absolute;
    bottom: 0;
    right: 0;
    z-index: 99 !important;
    width: 950px;
    height: 45px;
    line-height: 45px;
    padding: 20px;
    text-align: right;
    background: transparent url(img/bg_feature_story.png) top left no-repeat;
    color: #ffffff;
}
```

JavaScript:

```
$(function(){
    $(".slide").hide();
    $(".slide:first").show();
    $("#feature").css("background-image", "null");
  setInterval(function(){
    changeImage();
  },5800);

    $("#overlay").html( "" );
    $(".slide").each( function(){
        $("#overlay").append('<div class="slidetext" style="display:none;">' + $(this).html() + "</div>");  
        $(this).html("");
    });
    $(".slidetext:first").show();


  function changeImage(){
    var $currImg = $(".slide:visible");
    var $currText = $(".slidetext:visible");
    if ($currImg.next().length == 1) {
      var $next = $currImg.next();
      var $nexttext = $currText.next();
    } else {
      var $next = $(".slide:first");
      var $nexttext = $(".slidetext:first");
    }
    var bi = $currImg.css("background-image");
    $("#feature").css("background-image",  bi );
    $currImg.fadeOut( 100, function(){
    });
    $next.fadeIn( 1000, function(){
        $currText.hide();
        $nexttext.show();
    });
  }  
});
```

Answer (score 0):

I developed a plugin called [Basic jQuery Slider](http://basic-slider.com) - It's very simple to use and configure and very small filesize. Plus it supports any content, not just images. If you decide to try it out and have any questions, just ask!